# How to automate the update of html content?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to create a FB news feed like but for displaying content from database.
My code already reads the number of rows of the table but it needs to refresh the page before updating the content of the html.

Here is my code:

part of my html file:

```
<section id="reportcontent"></section>
<script>
    (function refreshNews()
    {
        $("#reportcontent").load("php/ajax.php");
    })();
    setInterval('refreshNews()',1000); 
</script>
```

content of ajax.php

```
<?php 
    require("database.php");

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM report";

    $res = odbc_exec($conn,$sql);

    while($feedItem = odbc_fetch_array($res))
    {
        echo "hello! <br>";
    }
?>
```

As you can see that every row of my table will echo a hello text. But in order to view the new number of rows i need to refresh the page. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work. You had your function name being passed as a string to the setInterval by wrapping it in ''. It should just be calling the function such as

```
setInterval('refreshNews',1000);
```

Also not sure if that was just a sample but the php code will not generate rows for a table. 
 is simply a line break.

Also while we're at it. It is poor practice to ever use intervals with Ajax calls. The reason being that the request could take longer than the interval time and you will end up with many calls running simultaneously. Use setTimeout instead inside the callback function of AJAX.load ()

```js
function refreshNews()
    {
       $("#reportcontent").load("php/ajax.php", function(){setTimeout(refreshNews, 1000);});
        
    }();


window.onload= function(){
    refreshNews(); 
  }
```

```html
<section id="reportcontent"></section>
```

Comment: no errors its just it doesn't update automatically still i need to refresh :)

Comment: if i put the section after the script it doesn't show the hello texts.

Comment: You should always try to have your scripts inside the head of the document which will mean that your script will be before the body. This will cause anything thats not fired by an event to be executed before the DOM properly loads. for this reason you will need to call everything inside of window.onload=function(){     }

Comment: see edited code above. Also to point out setInterval is a poor choice when using AJAX. The reason being is that it is possible that the AJAX call could take longer than the interval to complete and you end up with multiple AJAX instances being executed. Try using setTimeout instead.

Comment: @PC3TJ Your code using the timeout is neither waiting for ajax request to complete, it should be e.g: `$("#reportcontent").load("php/ajax.php", function(){setTimeout(refreshNews, 1000);});`

Comment: @A.Wolff thank you. Sorry wasn't thinking about AJAX being async.

Comment: thanks for the comments. first my practice is i put the scripts in the <head> tag as mentioned i was just trying this code i searched on other site and it was given it is inside the <body> hehehe... i'll try the comment of @A.Wolff

Comment: @A.Wolff answer is correct it functioned well! Thanks for your time guys! You really helped me. I don't know how to vote his comment as the correct answer though in return. :\

Comment: @mushroomgroover while his comment corrected a small flaw in my logic, it was a suggested edit of my answer. I have up voted his comment. However I believe this to be the correct answer